# Endless scrolling buffer is not honored

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I am trying to build a web app which displays images in a grid view. I have implemented a so called endless scrolling functionality and it works great. The problem is that I have added a 500 pixel buffer so that the loading of new images should begin before reaching the end of the page but this buffer is not honored. I have to scroll to the absolute bottom before it is triggered. What can I do?

I am using this solution: http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9445/

**This is my scrolling code:**

```
$(window).scroll (function () {

 if ($(window).scrollTop () >= $(document).height () - $(window).height () - 500) {

  if (!self.loading) {

   if (self.stop) { return; }

    if (!self.pause) { self.append (); }

   }

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery are you using? I've recently just implemented almost exactly what you're describing and it works perfectly. You may want to try looking at `$(document).offset()['top']` to see if your `body` element is moved up.

It's also possible that all the `if()` statements are slowing down your browser and with it the `scroll()` event rate. If this is happing, you might scroll deep into the buffer before the event is triggered.

Tips to speed this up:

- Move your simple/binary checks to before the complex comparison. That way, if they return false, you haven't wasted time calculating anything
- Replace the `>=` operator with `>` to save some (probably negligible) processing power.

If the below doesn't work, then it's either your version of jQuery or some other line of code.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
  if(!self.loading && !self.stop && !self.pause && ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > $(document).offset()['top'] + $(document).height() - 500){
    self.append();
  }
})
```

Cheers,

Mike